# woocommerce 3.2.1 not sending order notification emails

Tags: plugins, php, woocommerce-offtopic

Why woocommerce 3.2.1 not sending order notification emails to gmail, yahoo , ...
I have tested many ways to solving this problem like using smtp, disabling active plugins, testing other themes , ...
But nothing works and now I have installed older version (2.6.14) and is sending emails to inbox and works good.
I need latest version and need to fix it up. 
Help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly got it!
if you have my problem you can do following steps to make it work:
install [Easy WordPress SMTP](http://www.example.com/). It the only one that works.

And do what is said in this link :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25175234/2674546

Comment: Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the system status page in WooCommerce to see if there's anything not functioning properly?

Besides that you might want to see if it's actually a WooCommerce problem, or if for example [sendmail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) is not working. You can either check it in your PHP settings or by simply requesting a password change for your account and see if that email does arrive.

This has been a known issue in WooCommerce, and has apparently [arisen](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/14151) when the `woocommerce_defer_transactional_emails` filter has been introduced. Try and see if that's the issue by disabling it using this code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_defer_transactional_emails', '__return_false' );
```

If the problem persists, and you need your email back up and running asap I can recommend setting up a transactional email service like [Postmark](http://postmarkapp.com). Such services have always been the most reliable to me.

Comment: have done before what you said but not working....